# Finding a sequences so the image approximates integers

Tags: sequences-and-series, approximation, integer-programming

$x$ is fixed in $[0,1]$, $a_n,b_n,c_n$ are integers and not all of them are $0$

$y(a_n,b_n,c_n) = a_n x^3 + b_n x^2 + c_n x = Y_n$

Find an algorithm to go from $(a_n,b_n,c_n)$ to $(a_{n+1},b_{n+1},c_{n+1})$ where $Y_{n+1}$ is closer to an integer than $Y_n$

Preferably the algorithm would approximate extremely quickly with small coefficients(I believe I can prove that an optimal sequence exists in this sense)

The first thing that was suggested to me over IRC(#math on freenode) by muboto is to use continued fractions and the extended euclidean algorithm to find $n$ such that $np + mq = 1$ for the $p,q$ from the continued fraction. This doesn't seem to zoom very fast though(linear with the size of parameters if I judged it right).

I conjecture that it should be able to grow at least with the parameters to the third or fourth.

I have some data supporting it here

```
a,b, c,distance from an integer
5,1,-2,-0.00166826
5,5,-3,-0.0141376
5,6,-5,0.0111764
5,10,-6,-0.00129289
6,-9,-5,-0.000821762
6,-2,1,-0.0056958
6,0,-9,-0.000446392
6,3,-2,0.00714886
6,7,-3,-0.00532043
6,9,-13,-7.10226e-005
7,-19,-8,2.47379e-005
7,-10,-12,0.000400108
7,0,1,0.00312132
7,9,-3,0.00349669
8,-3,4,-0.000906223
8,6,0,-0.000530853
8,15,-4,-0.000155483
9,-13,1,-5.97227e-005
9,-4,-3,0.000315647
9,5,-7,0.000691017
11,-16,-30,3.81759e-005
11,-7,10,-0.000144183
11,2,6,0.000231186
11,11,2,0.000606556
13,-10,-21,-4.62847e-005
14,15,-13,-0.000601875
15,-4,-12,-0.000130745
15,5,-16,0.000244624
17,2,-3,-0.000215206
17,11,-7,0.000160164
17,295,17,-1.31322e-008
18,45,-3,-2.00573e-005
19,17,2,7.57032e-005
20,-29,-29,-2.15467e-005
20,-11,7,0.000171464
20,-2,47,-1.08954e-005
20,25,123,-2.44102e-007
21,23,11,-8.75739e-006
22,-5,16,8.70032e-005
22,48,-25,-6.61936e-006
23,-24,61,4.04531e-007
23,20,-20,8.91412e-005
24,1,25,2.54256e-006
25,26,-11,4.68059e-006
25,123,-133,-2.05265e-007
26,-73,-1,1.05316e-006
26,51,-47,6.81862e-006
27,-48,-37,3.1912e-006
27,-21,39,1.38425e-005
28,-147,-27,-4.36235e-007
28,4,3,1.59805e-005
29,29,-33,1.81186e-005
31,-196,-89,2.12398e-007
31,-18,17,2.72805e-005
31,35,-24,-6.6342e-005
32,7,-19,2.94185e-005
33,-12,26,-5.71801e-005
34,13,-10,-5.50421e-005
39,-368,-239,2.02658e-008
43,1,184,1.60429e-007
45,148,-10,-4.49367e-007
46,49,0,-4.0768e-006
47,74,-36,-1.93877e-006
48,-25,-26,-5.56619e-006
48,2,50,5.08512e-006
48,99,-72,1.99266e-007
49,27,14,7.22316e-006
50,52,-22,9.36119e-006
51,-171,34,-3.17039e-008
56,-73,-222,7.1336e-009
56,983,-205,-5.59139e-010
68,124,51,-4.48362e-008
70,50,25,-1.53423e-006
71,75,-11,6.03797e-007
72,-24,-1,-3.02363e-006
73,-834,-222,1.69412e-009
73,1,-37,-8.85602e-007
73,222,-205,-5.99863e-009
74,26,-73,1.25243e-006
94,51,50,1.00833e-006
96,-23,24,-4.81071e-007
97,2,-12,1.65696e-006
99,-72,-38,1.67562e-007
107,-244,-188,-2.45703e-008
116,223,-21,1.5443e-007
119,-47,85,-7.65401e-008
121,100,-109,-6.86336e-007
124,51,-171,-3.77026e-008
129,149,-427,1.13498e-009
142,-71,146,3.27991e-007
144,76,-48,-2.81805e-007
146,-612,-427,-4.30451e-009
146,444,-410,-1.19973e-008
147,27,-110,3.66828e-007
167,52,13,1.22726e-007
185,1132,-632,5.75837e-010
192,175,-120,-8.25387e-008
218,-119,47,9.1022e-008
225,-20,576,2.14704e-010
235,176,64,7.78898e-008
238,-94,170,-1.5308e-007
240,274,-192,1.16727e-007
243,4,-86,-1.14243e-007
281,-93,354,7.34831e-009
281,963,371,-3.44435e-010
286,5,98,4.61858e-008
291,103,-158,8.50234e-008
298,202,371,-5.78392e-009
332,-264,388,-2.43556e-008
337,-166,132,1.44819e-008
354,129,149,1.34968e-009
359,227,-107,4.01872e-008
388,-337,166,-1.7222e-008
405,-42,183,-3.03543e-008
410,56,-73,8.48328e-009
410,1112,-56,7.90541e-010
427,351,-56,-4.64894e-009
450,-40,1152,4.29409e-010
483,278,-278,2.48466e-009
500,573,-261,-1.06476e-008
506,943,947,-1.2973e-010
539,205,-500,9.61826e-009
556,500,-483,-3.51397e-009
579,109,725,1.56439e-009
612,427,-705,3.61963e-009
685,649,-910,-2.37899e-009
702,-1168,-927,-1.25738e-010
708,258,298,2.69936e-009
725,-503,298,-2.74012e-009
781,480,93,-3.29926e-009
837,407,-129,3.83434e-009
854,-354,-129,-1.60515e-009
910,629,-334,-2.16429e-009
927,-1188,-351,8.89665e-011
983,-205,-556,-4.70173e-010
1039,778,-761,-1.02931e-009
1079,-374,447,-1.39044e-009
1112,-56,-983,6.64803e-010
1168,927,-1188,1.05664e-010
1208,-225,20,-2.55468e-010
1264,758,-185,-8.14607e-010
1393,907,-612,3.20369e-010
1433,-245,596,-4.07636e-011
```

EDIT: I implememnted mobuto's solution in python as follows and the results obviously are inverse linear in terms of the parameters

```
from fractions import Fraction

x = 0.5**.25

def egcd(a, b):
    x,y, u,v = 0,1, 1,0
    while a != 0:
        q, r = b//a, b%a
        m, n = x-u*q, y-v*q
        b,a, x,y, u,v = a,r, u,v, m,n
    gcd = b
    return gcd, x, y

def findpq(x, i):
    tmp = Fraction(x).limit_denominator(100*i**2+1)
    return tmp.numerator,tmp.denominator


def f(a,b,c):
    return a*x**3 + b*x**2 + c*x

def nextabc(a,b,c,i):
    p,q = findpq(x*x*x,i)
    gcd, x1, y = egcd(p, q)
    p,q = findpq(x*x,i)
    gcd, x2, y = egcd(p,q)
    p,q = findpq(x,i)
    gcd, x3, y = egcd(p,q)
    return (int(x1), int(x2), int(x3))

a=1
b=1
c=1
for i in range(100):
    z = abs(f(a,b,c) - round(f(a,b,c)))
    print(a,",",b,",",c)
    print(z)
    a,b,c = nextabc(a,b,c,i)
```

Comment: There's a theorem of Dirichlet about how small you can make $|ar+bs+ct|$ with $a,b,c$ integers bounded by $N$ (and given reals $r,s,t$). The proof of the theorem gives you a way to find better triples $a,b,c$ as $N$ increases (though it might not be a very efficient way). In your case, $r,s,t$ are $x,x^2,x^3$.

Comment: Any idea where I can find the paper? A quick google doesn't seem to turn anything up

Comment: I found a reference to it here http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa16/aa1647.pdf but I can't seem to find a constructive proof of it like you were referencing @GerryMyerson

Comment: It's not so easy to find a good source for this result. Theorem 1C on page 27 of Schmidt, Diophantine Approximation, says for any real numbers $a_1,\dots,a_n$ and any integer $Q>1$ there exist integers $q_1,\dots,q_n$ and $p$ with $1\le\max(|q_1|,\dots,|q_n|)<Q^{1/n}$ and $|a_1q_1+\cdots+a_nq_n-p|\le1/Q$. Theorem 1E on page 28 is a generalization of this, and 1E is proved on page 29. The original reference is Dirichlet, Verallgemeinerung eines Satzes aus der Lehre von den Kettenbruchen nebst einigen Anwendungen auf die Theorie der Zahlen, S. B. Preuss. Akad. Wiss. (1842) 93-95.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Looking at Schmidt, Diophantine Approximation the proof is non-constructive(just a pigeon-hole argument). Is there a constructive proof that lets me construct the sequences of $a_n,b_n,c_n$?

Comment: Maybe you'll find something at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_relation_algorithm (and, if you do, you can write up a summary and post it as an answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PSLQ algorithm you can determine a,b,c to an arbitrary tolerance. I implemented this in python as follows

```
from sympy.mpmath import pslq

x = 0.5**.25

def f(a,b,c):
    return a*x**3 + b*x**2 + c*x - round(a*x**3 + b*x**2 + c*x)

def nextabc(a,b,c,i):
    return pslq([x**3,x**2,x,1], maxcoeff=i+1, tol=i**-3, maxsteps=10000)

a=1
b=1
c=1
pa = 0
pb = 0
pc = 0
print("a,b,c,n,f")
for i in range(10000):
    a,b,c,d = nextabc(a,b,c,i+1)
    if a != pa or b != pb or c != pc:
        print(pa,",",pb,",",pc,",",i+1, ',', f(pa,pb,pc), sep='')
        pa, pb, pc = a, b, c
print(pa,",",pb,",",pc,",",i+1, ',', f(pa,pb,pc),sep='')
```

This will always converge to a set of numbers because PSLQ converges if the solution with the given tolerances exist and by Dirichlet's simultaneous approximation theorem the solution of $|ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d| < n^{-3}$ in terms of $a,b,c$ exists for all x with $\max(a,b,c) \le n$. My implementation generates a csv file where the maximum $n$ the $a,b,c$ works for and the distance of $ax^3 + bx^2 + cx$ from an integer.

This doesn't give a nice form for them, but it is an algorithm to construct them which is all that was needed for the question.